# With 4 I deliver you, With 3 I trouble you, With 2 I kill you

Tags: riddle, word

I'm a four letter word:

> With four I deliver people.
> With three I trouble people.
> With two I kill people.

What word am I?

Comment: This is... what's the word? It's six, which is a hundred times five, which gives forceful advantage over four, which is always greater than three, which came before.

Comment: I really wanted to make something of how people are troubled by _tribulation_ and sometimes killed by _bibulation_; but I've never seen anyone delivered by _quadribulation_. (Unless "4" is "4 am"!) Sadly, "bulation" is not a four-letter word, either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> You are a TAXI

With four I deliver people.

> A taxi! Delivers people to and fro. Possibly clued too easy.

With three I trouble people.

> A tax! Nothing is certain but death and taxes!

With two I kill people.

> An ax! Speaking of death... an ax'll do the trick.

Comment: What is an 'ax'? Now, an 'axe' I am familiar with.

Comment: It's one of those short ones, easier to swing I think.  Just kidding.

Comment: @GlenYates See [ax vs axe](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=ax+vs+axe) :)

Comment: Thanks @riskymysteries I thought there was a difference

Answer (score 23):

Another answer that's also a bit of a stretch:

> You are a TIRE

With four I deliver people

> Most vehicles have four tires and are used to deliver people

With three I trouble people

> When you have a flat tire and are down to three tires on your car, you're in quite a bit of trouble

With two I kill people

> Motorcycles only have two tires, and are significantly more dangerous than cars; motorcyclists are 35 times as likely to be in a fatal accident than car drivers, per mile driven

Comment: I actually like this one a lot! Maybe it's my inexperience showing through, but this sort of Sphinx' Riddle thing is where my mind first went too.

Comment: 3 and 2 could also be "ire" and "IR (ionizing radiation)"

Comment: Neat. And what happens when 2) collides with 3)?

Answer (score 18):

I admit it's a stretch, but here's an alternative:

> You are the word FREE

With four I deliver people.

> Persons set FREE are delivered from bondage.

With three I trouble people.

> A FEE can cause hesitation to complete a transaction.

With two I kill people.

> FR (Fr) is the symbol for [Francium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium), a radioactive element that would be lethal if it weren't so short-lived.

Comment: Two is also a country-code, that could cause offense...

Comment: @smci - I KNOW, right?!?  I'm often offended by the French! :-p

Comment: @MrWonderful: careful to avoid spoilers...

Answer (score 13):

it's always a 4 letter word right?

> It's the letter E

> With four I dElivEr pEoplE.

> With three I troublE pEoplE.

> With two I kill pEoplE.

so either

> RUNE or SIGN would fit (just trying to find a 4 letter word for 'letter')

Comment: Or 'char' for the programmers here.

Comment: Haha I like this answer! Maybe you could get away with "FIVE", since E is the fifth letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

I know there's an accepted Answer, but I have another possibility.

You are:

> TRAM

With four you deliver people:

> Tram is another word for trolley or streetcar.

With three you trouble people:

> Ram, as in the male sheep. While fluffy, they are often very headstrong (literally and figuratively) and a will run you over (literally) if you get in their way.

With two you kill people:

> Ra is the periodic table symbol for radium, which is a highly radioactive element.

OR:

> Am is the periodic table symbol for Americium, which is also a highly radioactive element.

OR:

> AM (ante meridiem) is the designator for the morning hours, where people drive to work while sleepy and cause accidents. Ok, ok, so this is a bit of a stretch.

OR:

> Ra is a [sun god](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra). The sun can cause skin cancer, which can be deadly. Yes, this is another stretch.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> NNO O  - A mix of nitrous oxide and oxygen

With four you deliver people

> A mix of nitrous oxide and oxygen is used in delivery to help with labour pains - literally delivering (tiny) people.

With three you trouble people

> NNO - Nitrous oxide on its own can be worrying, slowly leading to hypoxia

With two you kill people

> Pure Nitrogen will suffocate you

Disclaimer:

> I'm aware that, technically, the first bit should be NNO + OO, oxygen doesn't like to be on its own.

Comment: But we already breathe 70% N2. So to compare, we'd have to go with both 100% N2 and also 100% N2O (which I am sure means more than just trouble)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yup, so 100% nitrogen will suffocate you. 100% nitrous oxide for a long time is definitely bad news (hence the eventual hypoxia) but more breathable than pure nitrogen. Really depends on where you draw the line for trouble.